# How do azure webjobs behave when any error or exception occurs in running webjob?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk, azure-webjobs-triggered

I want to release all objects if any exception or error occur in running webjob. How do I know if error occurred.Is there any error trigger working with webjob?

Comment: What kind of webjob are you talking about? Is it an executable or a script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be two approaches to handle this:

1) Try/Catch method:- You may trigger a mail or any action in catch block. In catch block you can send the info of the exception you got to your mail account or may even write to any DB table or add it to any queue.

2) Function Filter:- You may user function filter which has function exception filter attribute that is called on any exception situation. You may find the details here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Function-Filters

Also their is a piece of code from where you can take the reference:

```
public class ErrorHandlerAttribute : FunctionExceptionFilterAttribute
{

public override async Task OnExceptionAsync(FunctionExceptionContext exceptionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    string body = $"ErrorHandler called. Function '{exceptionContext.FunctionName}': {exceptionContext.FunctionInstanceId} failed. ";
    CombineErrorWithAllInnerExceptions(exceptionContext.Exception, ref body);

    string[] emailList = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SendErrorEmails"].Split(';');

    await SendEmail.SendErrorNotificationAsync("WebJob - Common Driver Error", body);
}

private void CombineErrorWithAllInnerExceptions(Exception ex, ref string error)
{
    error += $"ExceptionMessage: '{ex.Message}'.";
    if (ex is Domain.BadStatusCodeException)
    {
        error += $"Status code: {((Domain.BadStatusCodeException)ex).StatusCode}";
    }

    if (ex.InnerException != null)
    {
        error += $"InnerEx: ";
        CombineErrorWithAllInnerExceptions(ex.InnerException, ref error);
    }
} }
```

You may call it by decorating your method with "ErrorHandler" attribute. So, in case of any exception "OnExceptionAsync" function will be called.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any error trigger working with webjob?

About `ErrorTrigger` you could refer to this [wiki](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/wiki/Error-Monitoring). You could send email notification if you need or you could execute the method you write. In the doc, you can find some code samples details.

As for exception, you could catch exceptions and handle them with `try catch`.

Comment: @Namrata Rawool if my answer could help you, could you accept my answer.Thanks.